# CentOS 7 warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (fr_FR.UTF-8)

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, localization

I have this error when log in into a remote server throught ssh. The error also when I run a bash script.

I tried to reinstall glib with `yum reinstall glibc-common` but the error is still here.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comment out or delete the line "override_install_langs=en_US.utf8" in /etc/yum.conf.

Then reinstall glibc-common.

Comment: I reinstaled and loged out and everything is ok